# Distinct xor values of two strings

Tags: python, dynamic, bit-manipulation, xor

You are given two strings of length n, you have to find distinct xor values by rearranging the elements in an arbitrary way of the two strings.

Here is what I tried:

```
String1 = input()
String2 = input()
s1_ones = String1.count('1')  #Number of 1's in string1
s2_ones = String2.count('1')  #Number of 1's in string2

minimum_overlap = s1_ones+s2_ones-n  #minimum overlapping 1's when performing xor
maximum_overlap = min(s1_ones,s2_ones) #maximum overlapping 1's when performing xor

if(minimum_overlap<0):
    minimum_overlap = 0
ans = 0
for x in range(minimum_overlap,maximum_overlap+1):
    resulting_ones = s1_ones + s2_ones - 2*x   #number of ones in resulting string
    ans+=(nCr(n,resulting_ones)) #nCr is a function which returns number of possible values of resulting String.
print(ans)
```

I would like to explain nCr(n,r) funtion a little more. Given that you have string of length 5 in which number of ones are say 3. Here, N = 5  String = '11100' nCr(5,3) will give all the possible values of the provided string which is (5!/3!*2!) = 10.
What is wrong with this approach?

Here is the nCr(n,k):

```
def nCr(n, k): 
    if(k > n - k): 
        k = n - k 
    res = 1
    for i in range(k): 
        res = res * (n - i) 
        res = res / (i + 1) 
    return (res)
```

Comment: What are *"`distinct xor values`"*? *"`What is wrong with this approach?`"* -- that's what you have to tell us! What input did you use, what did you get, what did you expect?

Comment: As mentioned, distinct xor values are the values obtained from two given strings by rearranging their elements in an arbitrary way and performing xor operation. For eg. If a = '10' b ='00', distinct xor values are '10' and '01' so output should be 2. Now, this is a dynamic programming question and I am getting wrong answer as a  verdict so I don't happen to think of any test case which fails.

Answer (score 0):

I hope, This answers all your questions

```
import operator as op
from functools import reduce

import operator as op
from functools import reduce

def nCr(n, r):
    r = min(r, n-r)
    numer = reduce(op.mul, range(n, n-r, -1), 1)
    denom = reduce(op.mul, range(1, r+1), 1)
    return numer / denom

String1 = input()
String2 = input()
n=len(String1)
s1_ones = String1.count('1')
s2_ones = String2.count('1') 

minimum_overlap = max(s1_ones,s2_ones)-min(s1_ones,s2_ones)
zero=n-max(s1_ones,s2_ones)
x=min(s1_ones,s2_ones)
ans = 0
while zero>-1 and x>-1:
    zero-=1
    x-=1
    ans+=nCr(n,minimum_overlap)%1000000007
    minimum_overlap+=2
print(int(ans))
```

now this nCr function is faster than factorial version, but if it still take time to execute, you can use fermat's theorem for nCr%p (also precompute factorial array) which you can find on internet

Comment: For input 00 10 Output should be 2 but your code gives 3.